# Check to see if today is a certain date

Tags: shell

I want to check if the day is Sunday, but for some reason I can't get it to work.

```
[[ "date '+%a'" == "Sun" ]] && echo "Today is Sunday"
```

Comment: so the next question is how to run that in cron. Basically I want to run a certain script every third Sunday of the month, hence the need to check if the date falls on a Sunday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$(...)` to execute a command and return the output as a string:

```
[[ $(date '+%a') == "Sun" ]]
```

Comment: Better make that command "LC_ALL=C date +'%a'" or that shell script will cease to work as soon as someone runs it with a non-English locale set.

Comment: Or better yet, use `%w` so that it gives you a number.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the date +%u to get the day number of the week... 1 - 7 with Monday being 1 that way you should not have an issue with non-english locales

Comment: `[[ $(date '+%u') == "7" ]] && echo "Today is Sunday"` Great that you pointed this out. This is much more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[ $(date '+%a') == "Sun" ]] && echo "Sunday!"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case "$(date '+%a')" in "Sun" ) echo "sunday";; esac
```

Answer (score 0):

#### For completion:

If you have multiple locales I advise to use `+%u` cf. `man date`:

> %u     day of week (1..7); 1 is Monday

Today is monday:

```
date +%u
1
if [[ $(date +%u) -eq 1 ]]; then
  echo 'ho no :c'
fi
ho no :c
```

hth